# List DNS Servers Obtained Via DHCP

Tags: dns

Is there a way to list the DNS servers obtained through DHCP alongside IP addresses information (equivalent to the Windows command "ipconfig /all")? It seems needlessly tedious to run either "nmcli device show" or "cat /etc/resolv.conf" just for this information.

Answer (score 0):

You can shorten the `nmcli device show` to just `nmcli d sh`, which makes it shorter than the Windows command `ipconfig /all`. And if you need it so often, you can always create a command alias with as short a name as you wish.

For example:

```
alias i='nmcli device show'
```

Put that in your `~/.bashrc` or equivalent shell start-up file, restart your session, and now you'll have a new single-character command, `i`, that